# Sacar de la BD los mensajes compartido con cada usuario

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

Estoy intentando extraer de la base de datos el ultimo mensaje de cada conversación así como lo hace Facebook y las demás plataformas de mensajerías instantáneas.

**Por ejemplo yo quiero esto:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero solo he conseguido esto:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código que estoy utilizando para extraer los mensajes**

```
<?php
// Sacar los usuarios con los que he tenido una conversacion
$stetament = $conexion->prepare("
    SELECT users.id_user, users.name, users.surname, 
      users.photo_profile, messege.messege, messege.create_at_messege 
      FROM users INNER JOIN messege 
      WHERE messege.id_emisor = $id OR messege.id_receptor = $id
");

$stetament->execute(array());
$result = $stetament->fetchAll();
```

### Cual es mi objetivo ?

Mi objetivo es como la captura de arriba de mis conversaciones en Facebook. Quiero que me muestro un listado de las personas con las que yo he tenido conversaciones y me muestre el ultimo mensaje que hemos intercambiado, la fecha y etc.. como yo muestro en mi captura de pantalla

Tome el mismo código y lo ejecute en SQL de **phpmyadmin** y me devuelve este resultado que tal vez les pueda servir para un poco mas de información.

Comment: Tu pregunta es un poco confusa. ¿Quieres un solo registro o quieres varios registros o quieres ambas cosas, una lista de las últimas personas y el último mensaje? Si es una lista de las últimas personas, ¿hasta qué límite? Creo que `GROUP_CONCAT` te será de gran ayuda, pero aclara la pregunta, porque no he entendido. También se agradece ver los resultados en forma de texto.

Comment: Que tal compañero... La verdad es que quiero lo mismo que aparece en la captura de pantalla de Facebook, quiero un listado de las personas con las que he hablado y en ella aparezca 1 mensaje solo que este debe de ser el ultimo mensaje que se ha enviado en la conversación sin importar quien lo ha enviado. Justo como hace Whatsapp, facebook y las demás plataformas de mensajerías

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esa consulta es un poco más complicada de lo que parece. Quizá lo que más cuesta es localizar al interlocutor. Después ya es únicamente agrupar, combinar y ordenar. Aunque admite varias soluciones equivalentes, te propongo algo así para el `id_user=2`:

```
SELECT `name`,surname,
  create_at_messege,messege
  FROM (
    SELECT id_user,
      MAX(id_messege) id_messege
      FROM (
        SELECT id_receptor id_user,
          id_messege
          FROM messege
          WHERE id_emisor=2
        UNION
        SELECT id_emisor id_user,
          id_messege
          FROM messege
          WHERE id_receptor=2
      ) c1 GROUP BY 1  
  ) c2 JOIN messege USING(id_messege)
  JOIN users USING(id_user)
  ORDER BY id_messege DESC;
```

Para este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id_user int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(31),
  surname varchar(31),
  photo_profile varchar(127)
  );

CREATE TABLE messege(
  id_messege int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_emisor int,
  id_receptor int,
  create_at_messege datetime,
  messege text,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_emisor) REFERENCES users(id_user),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_receptor) REFERENCES users(id_user)
  );

INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Pablo'),('Pedro'),('Sofía');
INSERT INTO messege (id_emisor, id_receptor, create_at_messege, messege) VALUES
  (1,2,NOW(),'Hola, Pedro. Soy Pablo'),
  (2,1,NOW(),'Hola, Pablo. ¿Cómo estás? ¡Cuánto tiempo!'),
  (2,3,NOW(),'Hola, Sofía. ¿A qué no sabes quién me acaba de saludar?');
```

Obtendrás este resultado:

```
+-------+---------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| name  | surname | create_at_messege   | messege                                                 |
+-------+---------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Sofía | NULL    | 2021-03-03 21:24:19 | Hola, Sofía. ¿A qué no sabes quién me acaba de saludar? |
| Pablo | NULL    | 2021-03-03 21:24:19 | Hola, Pablo. ¿Cómo estás? ¡Cuánto tiempo!               |
+-------+---------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Espero que resuelva tu problema. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.